# How to escape html tags in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have form with different count of fields. User can input html tags and I need to escape them. I need itterate over all input elements and apply encodeURIComponent to each of element value and than use $.param() to send data. How to do that? Or might be somebody know more elegant solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Not. I have already seen that. It is not my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, `$(form).serialize()` is enough. If that doesn't work, you can first use `$(form).serializeArray()` to encode form elements as an array of names and values, then apply `encodeURIComponent` to some fields that need to be escaped. At last, call `$.param()`.

BTW, as a matter of fact, `serialize` is composed of `$.param` and `$(form).serializeArray`

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried jquery serialize?

```
$(form).serialize();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KvYa8/

Comment: Yes, my code here  var formData = $form.serialize();
        $.post($form.attr('action'), formData, function(data) {
            if (data && data.result) { And server throws errors about unsecure input

Comment: please provide jsfiddle of your code pls